# Should a critical section or mutex be really member variable or when should it be?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have seen code where mutex or critical section is declared as member variable of the class to make it thread safe something like the following.

```
class ThreadSafeClass
{
public:
    ThreadSafeClass() { x = new int; }
    ~ThreadSafeClass() {};

    void reallocate()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

        delete x;
        x = new int;
    }

    int * x;
    std::mutex m;
};
```

But doesn't that make it thread safe *only* if the *same* object was being shared by multiple threads? In other words, if each thread was creating its own instance of this class, they will be very much independent and its member variables will never conflict with each other and synchronization will not even be needed in that case!?

It appears to me that defining the mutex as member variable really reduces synchronization to the events when the *same* object is being shared by multiple threads. It doesn't really make the class any thread safer if each thread has its own copy of the class (for example if the class were to access other global objects). Is this a correct assessment?

Comment: A member `std::mutex` can be used to guards any given instance against concurrent access. This is usually desirable, rarely do you need to lock *all* instances of a class for multithreading. It might come up if you have a shared `static` member that needs to be guarded. In that case, use a `static std::mutex`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking if we agree with your reasoning?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux assume the class is writing a log file, it would make sense to make all instances synchronize when they they are writing to a file, even perhaps if it was writing to a database.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @zar I would suggest that you might be better off guarding the shared resource (in this case, the log file handle) rather than guarding all instances that use that shared resource.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Really that I had my understanding correct. A mutex as member variable will only lock that instance of the class if it were to be shared by multiple threads. It will NOT synchronize two seperate instances of the same class.

Comment: After all a single thread can not call more then one member function at the same time by definition.

Comment: @zar In your example, yes `ThreadSafeClass::reallocate` locks on an instance-by-instance basis.

Comment: @Galik That's not necessarily true. A member method can be recursive.[`std::recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) exists.

Comment: *But doesn't that make it thread safe only if the same object was being shared by multiple threads?* that is what thread safe means.  If the variable can be shared between multiple threads with no added synchronization provided by the user then it is thread safe.  Since day 1 before C++ even knew about threads a thread local variable has always been thread safe since there was ever only one thread that could access it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think some may not be able to differentiate this good enough that this way we are only making an `instance` of the class thread safe, not the whole class as such. I think it is misused in general because it may not be be understood well.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I do not see how having a non static member variable would make anyone think all instances of the class will share it.

Comment: The only reason I can see with having a static mutex in a class is if the class accesses another static member and that access needs to be thread safe across all instance in all threads interacting with that member.

Comment: A bit of a thought shift, but worth a read: [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that any given object will only be accessed by one thread then a mutex is an unnecessary expense. It however must be well documented on the class's contract to prevent misuse.

PS: `new` and `delete` have their own synchronization mechanisms, so even without a lock they will create contention.

EDIT: The more you keep threads independent from each other the better (because it eliminates the need for locks). However, if your class will work heavily with a shared resource (e.g. database, file, socket, memory, etc ...) then having a per-thread instance is of little advantage so you might as well share an object between threads. Real independence is achieved by having different threads work with separate memory locations or resources.

If you will have potentially long waits on your locks, then it might be a good idea to have a single instance running in its own thread and take "jobs" from a synchronized queue.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear, the intent and how we really want to share the class in many threads. Are we going to be sharing an instance between threads or each thread may create its own instance? This may not be very clear for some, but this kind of synchronization is of no use in the later case and is not even needed, it will only slows the performance. Maybe you want to add that specifically to your answer.

Comment: @zar Updated answer